# Has he come of age yet?

Tags: sentence-choice

> **Has he come of age yet?**

How do you usually ask that? As I understand it, the above-mentioned sentence isn't common (among Google books, on the internet). Why?

Comment: Have you found '[come of age](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-of-age)' in a dictionary?

Comment: @Michael Harvey, to reach the age when you are legally recognized as an adult [Cambridge Dictionary] What do I need to understand by your question?

Comment: Well, you don't ask it that way anymore. You would ask "Is he eighteen yet?" (or whatever age you're legally an adult wherever you are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a more common way of asking *that specific question*. I'm surprised that you find it to be uncommon; if it is, it's simply because it's not something we ask that often. "Coming of age" is a common enough topic (the other day I watched *The Sandlot*, and it was tagged with "coming-of-age"). And various cultures have various markers for it, like bar mitzvahs. We might be more likely to ask about these specific markers: Can he drive? Can he vote? Can he drink?

"Coming of age" is loosely defined in globalized modern culture, so unless the conversation has already identified parameters for it, the question can't be answered. If the conversation takes place in another culture, like turn-of-the-century high society or an orthodox Jewish community, then the parameters are understood.